# Mac Ventura external Display problems

Tags: macos, mac, external-display, macos-ventura

[image: Weird behaviour]

I have had weird* behavior since Mac OS Ventura on my M1 Max Macbook Pro 14". When I am using an external display then sometimes+ it starts with a partial resolution, keeping the rest of the screen black.

- weird:

- I have recorded a video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Di6sLotaRdQ
- It is weird. Some interface elements seem to work, while others do not.
- The mouse can go into the black area, but application windows do not.
- I am sure it started with Ventura or one of the minor updates afterward.

- Sometimes:

- It is not a 100% reproducible problem.
- I have seen this happening more often than not when I am switching external displays. Or going from the built-in laptop display to an external display.
- It does not matter if the external display is connected directly via HDMI, a Thunderbolt Hub or via one of apples adapters.

Am I the only one with this issue?
Something I can do about it?